# why does the the following code output the same address?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    char x[5] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
    printf("x=%p", x);
    printf("\n&x=%p", &x);
    return 0;
}
```

shouldn't the first statement print the address of x[0] while the second statement print the address of x, i.e the address of the array x

Comment: If I’m not mistaken. You’re not accessing the first index of the array “x” the first time but rather accessing the array as a whole. It should be printf(“x=%p, x[0]). IF I’m not mistaken.

Comment: Why do you expect address of `x[0]` to be different from address of `x`? Both `x[0]` and the whole `x` are located at the same address in memory. No wonder the printed addresses are the same.

Comment: Note that you get different values if you print `x + 1` and `&x + 1`.

Answer (score 2):

The address of an array *is* the address of the first element of that array.

In fact, the standard mandates that, except under limited circumstances, an array will decay to a pointer to its first element.

`x[n]` is defined as `*(x+n)` - if you use zero as the value of `n`, you should hopefully see that eqivalence